# Python Pandas: How to replace negative numbers by prior non-negative numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

Date | Value. 
2020-03-18 10 
2020-03-19 20 
2020-03-20 30 
2020-03-21 25 
2020-03-22 35 
2020-03-23 50 
2020-03-24 **-20**
2020-03-25 **-30** 
2020-03-26 50 
2020-03-27 25 
2020-03-28 35 
2020-03-29 40 
2020-03-30 **-10** 
2020-03-31 35 
... 
2021-01-31 45

What is the quickest way for me to replace the negative numbers in "value" column with prior non-negative values?

I need to be careful not to simply replace negative number with the immediate prior number, because it would mess up if the prior value is also a negative number (as seen in 2020-03-25).

I expect the end result be: 
Date | Value. 
2020-03-18 10 
2020-03-19 20 
2020-03-20 30 
2020-03-21 25 
2020-03-22 35 
2020-03-23 50 
2020-03-24 **50**
2020-03-25 **50** 
2020-03-26 50 
2020-03-27 25 
2020-03-28 35 
2020-03-29 40 
2020-03-30 **40** 
2020-03-31 35 
... 
2021-01-31 45

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Perhaps you can get some inspiration from how it can be done on a simple list (`arr`) using accumulate from itertools: `[*accumulate(arr,lambda a,b:[a,b][b>0])]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to your last question:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].where(df['Value'].ge(0)).ffill()
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I know what does ge(0) do here? Is that a detector for negative values?

Comment: Yes, `.ge(0)` means `greater than or equal to 0`. You can also replace that with `>= 0`